# Do I lose my achievements if I recover my Gamertag?

Tags: xbox-360, achievements

I was thinking about moving my Gamertag over to another storage device, but I'm afraid of losing all my achievements. If I just change the storage device and Recover Gamertag on the **same Xbox**, do I lose all my achievements?

Comment: this si first time i use this, please bee gentle...

Comment: It's no problem @Lars, just try to put a little more effort into writing your question next time :-) PS: Awesome edit @Kevin Y

Answer (score 6):

From [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907333):

> When you recover an Xbox LIVE
>   gamertag, all achievements and
>   gamerscores that you received while
>   connected to Xbox LIVE will be
>   recovered. However, you will lose your
>   offline achievements and gamerscores.

Comment: per Quantumgeek's comment below, this isn't entirely accurate. You'll lose only your offline achievements and gamerscore obtained **since your last connection to Xbox Live**. (Offline achievements and gamerscore are uploaded during your next connection, so if they've previously been uploaded, they'll be safe.)

Answer (score 1):

No, recovering your gamertag does not lose achievements.

Comment: This is only true if the xbox you are recovering from is connected to xbox live. For example, if you have an xbox that has not been connected to xbox live for a week, and you recover the profile to another xbox, you will lose any achievements you have gained over the last week.

Comment: @Quantumgeek Great answer, too bad I couldn't give you rep for the up vote, but +1 to you.